# Optimisation of difference between two real arrays by stretching.

Tags: optimization, least-squares

I have a [two set of experimental data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIbHV.png) and need to fit them to each other by the best way.

Formally saying. Given two constant real numbers arrays of $n$:
{${x_1, x_2, ... , x_n}$}, $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and 
{${y_1, y_2, ... , y_n}$}, $y_i\in\mathbb{R}$

There is need to find such real numbers $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}$ to minimize a sum

$$\arg\min_{a,b} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i - \left(ay_i + b \right)\right)^2$$

Comment: This is [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression).

Comment: Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2720664/edit) your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: @angryavian, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really. This is just a [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression). Earlier I thought that it helps to find a slope and intercept on Graph1, but actually you could use it to fit one graph to other by stretching as on Graph2 and Graph3.

[Graph1, Graph2 and Graph3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5GK5.png)

Graph2 - two sets of data before stretching and on Graph3 - after.